# Googleads PHP API how to setup access?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm feeling totally and utterly lost in a circle of documentation links without anything given me the answers I need.

What I want to achieve is simple, hit an API endpoint and get key data back for a campaign (cpc, clicks, impressions, costs etc). This will probably be set up on a cron to run every week.

Looking at the Github page here https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib it sends you to this link for setting up API access on behalf of your clients (web flow) https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/API-access-on-behalf-of-your-clients-(web-flow)

I have created a adwords clientID and client secret as per the instructions above but then the next steps are asking to redirect the users to a login page to confirm access?

Is there anyway around this as it's simply not going to work on a cron to pull in some data once a week, the user will have to manually do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to to setup OAuth2 for api access, you should follow [these](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/API-access-using-own-credentials-(installed-application-flow))  instructions .
So now you have your `adsapi_php.ini`  configured with your credentials, and it allows you to query the api.
Then you can use the `php sdk` to perform queries:

```
$dir = '/adsapi_php.ini' // the path of your .ini file;
require  '/vendor/autoload.php' // load the sdk;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
... // load what you need

 $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
     ->fromFile($dir)
     ->build();

 $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
     ->fromFile()
     ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
     ->build();

 $adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
```

This above is just an example, i suggest to look on [github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/tree/master/examples/AdWords/v201802) form more detailed and working examples.

**Edit**
For have statistics about one campaign, you have to do a [Criteria performance report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/criteria-performance-report).
This is an example of code that usual i use: (note that is a part of a big application probably not working straight out the box). it generate the last week report for a campaign.

```
$dir = 'path/to/adsapi_php.ini';
require  'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupAdService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\PolicyApprovalStatus;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\SortOrder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\ExpandedTextAd;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupAdOperation;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupAdStatus;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201802\DownloadFormat;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201802\ReportDefinition;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201802\ReportDefinitionDateRangeType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201802\ReportDownloader;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettingsBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Predicate;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\PredicateOperator;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\DateRange;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
    ->fromFile($dir)
    ->build();

  $adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();

  $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
      ->fromFile()
      ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
      ->withClientCustomerId($accountId)
      ->build();

getaveragestats($oAuth2Credential, $session,$accountId,$campaignid,$campaingname);
      function getaveragestats($oAuth2Credential, $session,$accountId,$campaignid,$campaingname){

        $oneweekago = strtotime("-1 week");
        $oneweekAgo = date("Ymd",$oneweekago);
        $datefrom = $oneweekAgo;
        $dateto =  date("Ymd");
        $selector = new Selector();
        $selector->setDateRange(new DateRange($datefrom, $dateto));
        $selector->setFields(['Date','Impressions','AveragePosition','AverageCpc']);
        $selector->setPredicates([
               new Predicate('CampaignId', PredicateOperator::IN, [$campaignid])]);
        $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
        $reportDefinition->setSelector($selector);
        $reportDefinition->setReportName('Report per la campagna #' . $campaignid);
        $reportDefinition->setDateRangeType(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::CUSTOM_DATE);
        $reportDefinition->setReportType(ReportDefinitionReportType::CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);
        $reportDefinition->setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat::CSV);

        // Download report.
        $reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
        $reportSettingsOverride = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())
            ->includeZeroImpressions(false)
            ->build();
            $reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReport($reportDefinition, $reportSettingsOverride);

            $reportAsString = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
            $your_array = array_filter(explode("\n",$reportAsString));
            $titolo = $your_array[0];
            $rowNames = $your_array[1];
            $rowNames = explode(",", $rowNames);
            $total = end($your_array);
            $tot = explode(",", $total);
            $result = [];
            for ($x = 2; $x < (count($your_array)-1); $x++) {
                $row =  explode(",", $your_array[$x]);
                $tmp = array(
                  'data'=>$row[0],
                  'impressions'=>$row[1],
                  'position'=>$row[2],
                  'cpc'=> intval($row[3])/100000
                );
                $result[]=$tmp;
            }
            function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
                return strtotime($a["data"]) - strtotime($b["data"]);
            }
        $avrg = getAverage($result);
        return $avrg
      }
```